# ArcGIS difference reclassify tool properties symbology

Tags: arcgis-desktop, reclassify

Is there a difference between the reclassify tool and just changing the ranges of a layer within the properties>symbology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious difference is that the reclassify tool will create a new file, while the symbology is stored in the layer file but does not change the input data set. This file will usually be markedly smaller than your input file thanks to better compression, which could speed up display and analysis.

Most processing tools will look at the data instead of the classes that are visible in the layer. (There are some exceptions, such as the ArcScan tools)

The reclassify tool will also allow you to enter new values that are not necessarily ordered, and to define "No data".